# Jquery Draggable and Droppable Z-Index with Relative Container or Fixed Panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, draggable, droppable

I am having a problem with Jquery Draggable and Droppable where the drag item is behind a fixed position side panel.

[image: Draggable should be over the Side Panel]

The parent draggable #gallery container has to have relative positioning because I am using Muuri for the grid layout.

```
  #gallery { position: relative; width: 65%; z-index:1 }
```

The side panel has a fixed position so that it can act like a slideout panel. If I put a z-index on the side panel it appears over the container as it should, but the drag item always appears behind it instead of respecting the higher z-index of the ui-dragging item. If I remove the z-index on the side panel, then the side panel obviously goes behind the container when it should be over the top.

```
#trash { position: fixed; z-index: 2; width: 200px; }
```

I set the drag item z-index in CSS.

```
.ui-draggable-dragging {z-index:4; }
```

I tried attaching the clone to the document and setting a zIndex:

```
$( "li", $gallery ).draggable({
      cancel: "a.ui-icon", 
      revert: "invalid", 
      containment: "document",
      helper: "clone",
      cursor: "move",
      zIndex: 5
    });
```

- The #gallery container needs to be relative and is z-index 1
- The #trash side panel is fixed position and is z-index 2
- The drag item should be at the highest z-index: 3+

I am using one of the standard Droppable examples to simplify the example. I have removed Muuri from the example to rule that out.

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/0SZ5Mjanh6sowC2uVnjS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to solve, update only one line code. please update your code add new CSS line

```
#gallery,
#trash  { z-index: inherit !important; }
```

See Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/Y3SwKJj0RZswlVKOnVhW?p=preview

Comment: Hi, that does not work. If you shrink the window so the side panel #trash overlays the container #gallery, the container will shake and stutter as the drag-item is dragged.

Comment: There are actually two problems. Steps to reproduce problems: 1) Minimize window so #trash is over #gallery. 2) Just mouse over the #trash. The gallery appears above the trash. For the stuttering, 2) Drag an item over the trash but do not release. 3) While holding down left mouse, move the cursor with the drag item up and down over the overlapping area. The trash and gallery flicker the z-index back and forth. Tested in FF and Chrome latest.

Comment: please review again my ans

Comment: Yes, changing to inherit made it work without stuttering. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the parent element, he is under the **thresh**, a easy workaround would be change the parent `z-index` when you drag the element. Change your draggable function for the code below, should work just fine.

```
    // Let the gallery items be draggable
    $( "li", $gallery ).draggable({
      cancel: "a.ui-icon", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
      revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
      containment: "document",
      helper: "clone",
      cursor: "move",
      zIndex: 5,
      drag:function () {
        $(this).parent().css('z-index', '9999');
        $(this).removeClass('droped');
      },
      // removing the CSS classes once dragging is over.
      stop:function () {
        $(this).parent().css('z-index', '1');
        $(this).addClass('droped');
      },
    });
```

Comment: I see what you mean, however, this does not work because that makes the whole #gallery overlay on top of the side panel. The side panel always needs to be above the gallery.

Comment: I see, I knew that, but I tought was not a problem :p

Comment: Is there a way to attach the clone to a different parent element? I thought that was what the 'containment' property did-assign the clone to the root document.

Comment: That would be a way to go, but I think you already solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

changed `z-index` of `#trash` to `-1`

```
#trash {
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 18em;
    padding: 1%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #e4e4e4;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: That does not work. The Trash side panel has to be above the #gallery main container.